# how to test if a string DON'T match using protractor

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm migrating my `karma-ng-scenario` tests suite to protractor. I would like to do something like

```
// karma-ng-scenario
expect(element('legend').text()).not().toBe("LOGIN_CONNECT");
```

in the protractor way. But it seems there isn't a `not()` function.

I'm using `angular-translate` to bind the LONGIN_CONNECT string into multiple languages and I want to test if the string is translated.

More globally, is there a a way test if something is different ? ... don't have a class, don't exists on the page, is not selected, ...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is definitely worth looking at the [API docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api). I have these open pretty much all the time.
There are lots of Web Driver functions you can use like `isEnabled()`, `isDisplayed()`, `isSelected()` etc. Protractor uses Jasmine syntax so you can use '.toBe(false)' to assert things are false.
To check for classes, you can do something like:

`expect(myElement.getAttribute('class')).toContain('my-class-name');`

To compare strings and assert that they do NOT match you could use `.not`. [Jasmine docs](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Matchers)
say:

> Every matcher's criteria can be inverted by prepending .not:
>
> expect(x).not.toEqual(y); compares objects or primitives x and y and
> passes if they are not equivalent

Comment: my fault ! 
I'm pretty new in jasmine, karma, protractor and there is a lot of things to learn ... I confused the `not` jasmine function and the `not()` karma function !

It works fine with 
    expect(web.findElement(by.tagName('legend')).getText()).not.toMatch("LOGIN_CONNECT");

Answer (score 5):

You can use something like:

```
expect(model.getText()).not.toContain('abcdef');
```

There is a `.not` property nowadays.

Comment: This is the most elegant solution in my version of jasmine/protractor

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the following to check for NOT matching:

```
expect(element('legend').text() === "LOGIN_CONNECT").toBe(false);
```